# WPF DataGrid2D ItemsSource Memory Leak

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridview, memory-leaks

I have a graph item and matrix item. Graph item is canvas where i draw ellipses and lines. In Matrix item I contains matrix. And I used this library
(xmlns:dg2d="clr-namespace:DataGrid2DLibrary;assembly=DataGrid2DLibrary")
(http://www.mediafire.com/?tm1arm230rr1tgi) to bind my 2d matrix to datagrid. But I noticed that before i click on matrix item as soon as the program has just started, i mean firstly i work with graphs. Canvas draws very fast, but after i clicked on matrix item and itemsource has worked when i back to graph again it draws very slowly. Also, I noticed a lot of memory after itemssource.

In this code I'm trying to null ItemsSource and clear memory

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void MatrixData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MatrixMenu.IsChecked)
            {
                if (DrawingCanvas_Undirected.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || DrawingCanvas_Directed.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    GraphItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                MatrixItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                MatrixAdj.ItemsSource2D = null;
                MatrixInc.ItemsSource2D = null;
                MatrixMenu.IsChecked = false;
                GC.Collect();


            }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="MatrixItem" Visibility ="Collapsed">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="149*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="285*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Canvas>
                <dg2d:DataGrid2D x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="MatrixAdj" 
                     VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                     Canvas.Left="411" Canvas.Top="20"
                     Width="350" Height="289"
                     AlternationCount="2"
                     UseModifiedDataGridStyle="True"
                     ItemsSource2D="{Binding Int2DList}"
                     RowBackground="White"
                     AlternatingRowBackground="#ebebeb"                       
                     Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />


            </Canvas>
            <Canvas Margin="4,2,-4,265" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <dg2d:DataGrid2D x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="MatrixInc" 
                             Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="20"
                             Width="350" Height="289"
                             AlternationCount="2"
                             UseModifiedDataGridStyle="True"
                             ItemsSource2D="{Binding Int2DList}"
                             RowBackground="White"
                             VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                             AlternatingRowBackground="#ebebeb"                       
                             Background="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

So the question is: how do i save that canvas drawing speed after click on matrixitem?

Answer (score 0):

solved by just removing datagrid when it's not active (delete datagrid from canvas child elements)

Comment: When answering your own question it helps others to mark the answer as Accepted.